# OpenLayers measurment path in 31700 projection

Tags: coordinate-system, distance, openlayers-2

I have this code who works great for distance measurment on 900913 projection with 4326  display projection (bing maps + layer WMS):

```js
measureDistanceControl = new OpenLayers.Control.Measure(
                  OpenLayers.Handler.Path, {
                    persist: true, // 1
                    immediate: true, // 2
                    displaySystem: 'metric', // 3
                    eventListeners: {
                        'measure': measure2,
                      'measurepartial': updateDisplay // 4
                    }
                  }
                );

                function updateDisplay( event ) { // 5
                    var mesaj= event.measure + ' ' + event.units;
                    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML=mesaj;
                };

                function measure2(event)
                {
                var mesaj= event.measure + ' ' + event.units;
                    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML=mesaj;
                }


    }

    function measure()
    {
        map.addControl( measureDistanceControl );
        measureDistanceControl.activate();
        document.getElementById("cancel").style.display = "inline";
    }
    function cancel_measure()
    {
        measureDistanceControl.deactivate();
        map.removeControl( measureDistanceControl );
        document.getElementById("cancel").style.display = "none";
    }
```

When I insert the code to a page with a layer and 31700 projection it sends NaN error. Code:

```js
 map = new OpenLayers.Map({
    div: "map",allOverlays: true, projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:31700"),
   allOverlays: true,maxResolution: 0.4651995555350368, maxExtent: bounds,
    layers: [

        data=new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS("data","http://127.0.0.1:8080/geoserver/data/wms",{layers: 'morino:<?php echo $data; ?>_space',transparent: true, format: 'image/png', <?php if ($tic!="") { ?>CQL_FILTER: "id_ddd=<?php echo $eras; ?>"<?php } ?>},{isBaseLayer: true, opacity: 0.9, singleTile: true }),
        wfs

    ],
    controls: [
        new OpenLayers.Control.Navigation({
            dragPanOptions: {
                enableKinetic: true
            }
        }),
        new OpenLayers.Control.PanZoom(),
        new OpenLayers.Control.Attribution()
    ],
    //center: new OpenLayers.LonLat(26.1473586305531, 44.4431676053183).transform(new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"), new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:31700")),
    zoom: 15
});
```

I've searched on Google but I didn't find anything to help me. I also read OpenLayers Cookbook - but the examples are only for 4326 projection. Or maybe OpenLayers doesn't support 31700 projection (or other then 4326)?

**EDIT** Solution found. Add this in header

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/proj4js/proj4js-compressed.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
     Proj4js.defs["EPSG:31700"] = "+proj=sterea +lat_0=46 +lon_0=25 +k=0.99975 +x_0=500000 +y_0=500000 +ellps=krass +towgs84=33.4,-146.6,-76.3,-0.359,-0.053,0.844,-0.84 +units=m +no_defs";
    </script>
```

Use proj4js v1 because proj4js v2 has a problem with openlayers2. I used http://svn.osgeo.org/metacrs/proj4js/trunk/lib/proj4js-compressed.js

Comment: according [to this](http://dev.openlayers.org/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Projection-js.html) OL2 only supports 4326 and 900913 out-of-the-box. You might be able to use the proj4JS library to support this projection, though.

Comment: You can definitely use other projections with OL2.  You'll need to create a definition like : ```//31700
Proj4js.defs["EPSG:31700"] = "+proj=sterea +lat_0=46 +lon_0=25 +k=0.99975 +x_0=500000 +y_0=500000 +ellps=krass +towgs84=33.4,-146.6,-76.3,-0.359,-0.053,0.844,-0.84 +units=m +no_defs"```

Comment: When I include proj4js.defs the WMS stops working. I have a WFS layer for zooming when filter is set. Seems from geoserver logs that he can't read the WFS layer. But in Firebug, the WFS layer is submited ok. I set geodesic true on measurment control - now I have some values, but are wrong.

Comment: Solution found: use proj4js v1. I used http://svn.osgeo.org/metacrs/proj4js/trunk/lib/proj4js-compressed.js added proj4j def for 31700 from @nmtoken Seems like openlayers 2 has a "problem" with proj4js v2.